# How do I solve the IVP $Y^{''}-8Y^{'}+16Y = 2\cos(x)$ with $y(0)=1$ & $y^{'}(0)=2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have gotten as far as getting the complimentary function :

$$y(x) = (A_1x+A_2)e^{4x}$$

But I don't know how to go about the particular solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the homogeneous part, guess $y_h=ce^{rt}$:

$$r^2e^{rt}-8re^{rt}+16e^{rt}=0$$

$$r^2-8r+16=(x-4)^2=0$$

so $r=4$ and we have $y_h=c_1e^{4t}+c_2te^{4t}$.

For the particular solution, guess $y_p=c_3\cos x+c_4\sin x$. Then $y_p'=c_4\cos x-c_3\sin x$ and $y_p''=-c_3\cos x-c_4\sin x$.

We have

$$(-c_3\cos x-c_4\sin x)-8(c_4\cos x-c_3\sin x)+16(c_3\cos x+c_4\sin x)=2\cos x$$

$$(15c_3-8c_4)\cos x+(15c_4+8c_3)\sin x=2\cos x$$

thus we have the system

$$15c_3-8c_4=2$$
$$8c_3+15c_4=0$$

Now you can solve for all four constants and obtain $y=y_h+y_p$.

Comment: I can see what you've done here but I learned once that if the RHS is of the form $A_1$Sin(Bx) + $A_2$Cos(Bx) where $A_1$ or $A_2$ equal zero then you cannot use $y_p$ = $c_3$ cos(x) + $c_4$ sin(x) ? Is this not the case then?

Comment: You may be thinking of when the RHS is $x\sin x$? There is a nice table about a third of the way down here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx

Comment: I thought so too but this isn't the case in the notes so I'm confused?

Comment: Dunno. I believe wolfram gave the same answer though.

Comment: Cheers anyway!!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

As $x=i$ is not a root of the characteristic equation, you will look for a particular solution of the form

$$y_p=A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have your complementary solution and your equation is clearly non-homogeneous, you can use the method of undetermined coefficients to find your particular solution which I think would be
\begin{equation}
y_{p}(x)=B_{1}cos(x)+B_{2}sin(x)
\end{equation}
where the $B_{i}$'s are constants
from here its a straightforward procedure

Answer (score 1):

A more rigorous method to evaluating the solution of a non-homogeneous linear ODE is using [Variation of Parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters). Essentially, the methodology is identical to what others have shown (Method of Undetermined Coefficients), however without having to 'guess' the form of the particular solution $y_p$.

This [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjmWR4kRtVk) shows an example using Variation of Parameters for the differential equation $\frac{d^2{y}}{dx^2}-\frac{dy}{dx}-2y=4x^2$.

Alternatively, there are also [written notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx) for the method, with some examples.

Note: The Wronskian determinant matrix is of the form:
$W= \begin{vmatrix}
f_1(x) & f_2(x) & \cdots & f_n(x) \\
f_1'(x) & f_2'(x) & \cdots & f_n' (x)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
f_1^{(n-1)}(x)& f_2^{(n-1)}(x) & \cdots & f_n^{(n-1)}(x)
\end{vmatrix}$